# Error TypeError: Object(...) is not a function (OneSignal )

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I create a new Ionic project and I install OneSignal, I always get an error when I run the "ionci cordova run android" command on my smartphone

```
vendor.js:2085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at OneSignal.startInit (vendor.js:81052)
    at main.js:185
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5396)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5387)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5387)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at i.isUsingGlobalCallback.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at n (polyfills.js:3)
```

the command lines used :

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
npm install @ionic-native/onesignal
```

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal/ngx';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
      OneSignal,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {OneSignal} from "@ionic-native/onesignal/ngx";
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  signal_app_id:string = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  firebase_id:string = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, oneSignal: OneSignal) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

        oneSignal.startInit(this.signal_app_id, this.firebase_id);
        oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);

        oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((res) => {
            // do something when notification is received
            console.log(res);
        });

        oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((res) => {
            // do something when a notification is opened
            console.log(res);
        });

        oneSignal.endInit();

    });
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "onesignal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "2.4.6",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to create the project again from the beginning but I have the same problem every time.

When installing with :

```
ionic start onesginal blank
```

I get these alerts :

```
npm WARN deprecated sw-toolbox@3.6.0: Please migrate to Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@5.2.11: Switch to @angular/common/http - see https://angular.io/guide/http
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
```

I also get the following alert when I install npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal :

```
found 1 vulnerabilities (1 high)
```

The problem can come from this?

Thanks you !

PS : I use Ionic 4

Comment: are you using ionic 3 or 4? can you include dependancies from package.json?

Comment: Please read the linked post. You maybe using cli v4. However app version is 3 as per `ionic-angular`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand ... how to correct?

Comment: You need to use `@ionic-native/onesignal` v4. Your ionic version  is **3**. For ionic v4, use @ionic-native/onesignal v5.x . The issue is the same for all ionic native wrappers. Docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/onesignal/#installation

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks a lot for your help !